# Javascript POST function only sending to one POST location

Tags: javascript, forms, discord, webhooks

Im trying to send HTML form data to 2 discord webhooks but it will only ever send to the second one. It displays no error messages or anything but it just doesn't send to the second webhook.

```js
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("POST", "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/920367877704523816/LpIHlNUfEsd0_lG5DWVL7zvCTSZQewmXYQprHnWpWNBESnVJnvVYF3JG9-SCZCzTpLcl");
      request.open("POST", "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/919233892538540103/C75vznMMpgv2qqecF5Tmjw7C1xcLFlVSrMuCvdZ6Zg4jUsJrFkLSg6--ZRMN_lN809yp");
     
      request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
      
      const params etc...

      request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

Comment: It's maybe because the method `open` redefines the link `send` is supposed to send a request to. I don't know if it's clear but maybe trying to do this in a loop will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create 2 separate request objects, you set a post url to the same request twice so it's taking the last one assigned

```js
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("POST", "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/920367877704523816/LpIHlNUfEsd0_lG5DWVL7zvCTSZQewmXYQprHnWpWNBESnVJnvVYF3JG9-SCZCzTpLcl");
      const request2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("POST", "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/920367877704523816/LpIHlNUfEsd0_lG5DWVL7zvCTSZQewmXYQprHnWpWNBESnVJnvVYF3JG9-SCZCzTpLcl");
      request2.open("POST", "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/919233892538540103/C75vznMMpgv2qqecF5Tmjw7C1xcLFlVSrMuCvdZ6Zg4jUsJrFkLSg6--ZRMN_lN809yp");
     
      request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
      request2.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
      
      const params etc...

      request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
      request2.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

you can also move your urls to an array and iterate it like this

```js
["https://discord.com/api/webhooks/920367877704523816/LpIHlNUfEsd0_lG5DWVL7zvCTSZQewmXYQprHnWpWNBESnVJnvVYF3JG9-SCZCzTpLcl", "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/919233892538540103/C75vznMMpgv2qqecF5Tmjw7C1xcLFlVSrMuCvdZ6Zg4jUsJrFkLSg6--ZRMN_lN809yp"].forEach((url) => {
      const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("POST", url);
     
      request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
      
      
      const params etc...

      request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
})
```

Comment: Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want two requests instead of redefining the one you have.

```js
const requestDiscordOne = new XMLHttpRequest();
      requestDiscordOne.open("POST", "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/920367877704523816/LpIHlNUfEsd0_lG5DWVL7zvCTSZQewmXYQprHnWpWNBESnVJnvVYF3JG9-SCZCzTpLcl");
   
      requestDiscordOne.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
      
      const params etc...

      requestDiscordOne.send(JSON.stringify(params));

      const requestDiscordTwo = new XMLHttpRequest();

      requestDiscordTwo.open("POST", "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/919233892538540103/C75vznMMpgv2qqecF5Tmjw7C1xcLFlVSrMuCvdZ6Zg4jUsJrFkLSg6--ZRMN_lN809yp");
     
      requestDiscordTwo.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
      
      const params etc...

      requestDiscordTwo.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

Obviously optimizing for reusability and stuff, but hope you get the idea.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Like others have already stated, the second `open` call re-initializes the request.

But do yourself a favour and use the [Fetch API](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_api_fetch.asp) for HTTP requests. It's cleaner and much easier to use. Especially in combination with `async/await`.

```js
async function getSomething() {
  const response = await fetch('/someApiUrl');

  // Waits until the request completes...
  console.log(response);
}
```